# Directive link function

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to create an ajax loader using directive. In link function I use show and hide function but I got error

```
elem.show is not a function
at Object.fn (loaderDirectives.js:15)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:11814)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12067)
at done (angular.js:7838)
at completeRequest (angular.js:8026)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:7982)

 elem.hide is not a function
at Object.fn (loaderDirectives.js:17)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:11814)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12067)
at done (angular.js:7838)
at completeRequest (angular.js:8026)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:7982)
```

My directive code is

```
 angular.module('movieApp.loader.directives', []).directive('loaderDirective',['$http',function($http){
    return{
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.isLoading = function(){
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function(v){
                if(v){
                    elem.show();
                }else{
                    elem.hide();
                }
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). There is no `show()` or `hide()` function in AngularJS's jqLite.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved using ng-show in the template.

```
  angular.module('movieApp.loader.directives', []).directive('loaderDirective',['$http',function($http){
    return{
        transclude: true,
        restrict : 'AEC',
        template: '<img  ng-show="showElem" src="assets/img/giphy.gif" alt="loading...">',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            scope.isLoading = function(){
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function(v){
                if(v){
                     scope.showElem = true;
                }else{
                     scope.showElem = false;
                }
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but if you're trying to do simple overlay on loading data, I think your approach is not so great.

Imagine a function you call and it responds with data. After you get data back you would probably use promises to expose data to scope. Before you call that Ajax request, you would put some variable isLoading to overlay div using ng-show="isLoading" and set it to true, after you get back the data from promise or if it gets rejected you set that variable isLoading=false. And overlay will show/hide if request is in progress.

If you put more code on some fiddle I could help you. Also you're not using element correctly, to use .show() and .hide() on element you would need jQuery.